# Appengine dashboard: Difference between Requests/Second and Req/Sec

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm doing some analysis on my Appengine project and I found a rather large discrepancy between the Requests/Second (cq. Request by Type/Second) chart and the Req/Sec table shown on the same page.

Current values:

- Requests/Second: ~ 37.5 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HAf2f.png))
- Requests by Type/Second (Dynamic Requests): ~20 ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcI9U.png))
- Req/Sec current (added up): ~ 8.8 (https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrEfF.png)

From the docs:

> Requests/Second: The number of URIs requested from your application every second, including dynamic, static, and cached requests.

And:

> The "Req/Sec" column lists the short-term request rate of each URI.

I would expect that at least Dynamic Requests/Second would be similar to Req/Sec. However there is still a factor 2 difference between those two.

How should these numbers be interpreted?

Answer (score 0):

The chart **Requests/Second** is equal to **Dynamic Requests** + **Static Requests** + **Cached Requests**.

**The Req/Sec current** is equal to Dynamic + Static + Cached requests your application currently handles for a particular path.

Comment: But then Requests/Second should be equal to Req/Sec right? For me this is not the case (about a 4 times difference between the two).

Comment: I calculated the total number of Req/Sec by adding up the numbers in that column (see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/XrEfF.png). The Request/Second I read from the chart. So this gives 37.5 / 8.8 ~= 4